# binary not in PATH variable - how to execute it?

Tags: bash

There is a binary in my home directory: "foo"
My PATH variable doesn't contains my home dir. 
I cannot change my PATH varible, since it's read-only

**Question:** How can I execute this binary without using the following:

```
./foo
. ./foo
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why _not_ use one of those, or `~/foo`?

Comment: I cannot have any "/" in my commands

Comment: Can you explain why that is? `bash foo` doesn't have a slash in it after all...

Comment: Is the actual question "how can I run an arbitrary executable in a restricted shell"?

Comment: you cannot execute a binary as "bash foo" my bad, updated

Comment: Or is the question "what's the difference between the three ways of running programs"?

Comment: @LoukiosValentine79: Neither can you execute __binary__ files as `. ./foo`.

Comment: Here is another similar question which discusses a similar approach, although not exactly what you are asking, but can give you some ideas - https://askubuntu.com/questions/164180/different-ways-of-executing-binaries-and-scripts .

Comment: You may also want to read the second part of this answer where I go into some detail about background knowledge.. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197378/use-alternatives-or-adding-to-path/197381#197381

Comment: Please read comments, and then update question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

create a parse.sh file with content:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:./
foo
```

execute with `bash --noprofile --norc parse.sh`